# How to set zoom level beyond 15 in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

How do we set zoom level in Google Maps?

We can set zoom level to 15 but how can we set zoom level to more than 15?

Answer (score 1):

Please try following code. It might help you

When you instantiate a google maps object using: new google.maps.Map(domElement, options)

You can can use options to set (among other things) the zoom level.

The default zoom level can be set using { zoom: 14 } for example.

After you create you google maps object, you can change the zoom level using setZoom()

```
var myMap = new google.maps.Map(
document.getElementById('map-canvas'), 
{ zoom : 14 } 
);
myMap.setZoom(12);
```

Detail please click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8717279/what-is-zoom-level-15-equivalent-to)

Comment: @user15284 if you think above answer was helpful for you then please accept the answer (small green color sign)..thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on which map is currently set as base layer, because satellite and street map layers go deeper than terrain map.